# Angular Materials Modal: Why is my variable undefined in the subscribe but not in the map method?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 6 with Angular Materials.

In my modal I have:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between" >
  <button color="primary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="false">Cancel</button>
  <button color="primary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="gizmo">{{inEditMode === true ? "Save" : "Add"}}</button>
</div>
```

So the modal will return either false (if the user clicks cancel) or returns the gizmo object (if the user clicks add).

In the class that calls the modal I have the following code.
When I debug the x variable does contain the gizmo object.  However as soon as that completes x is then undefined in the subscribe.  Why is that?  Shouldn't x contain the gizmo as it did in the map?

```
addGizmo() {
    let gizmo = new Gizmo();
    this.tagSubject.next(gizmo);

    let dialogEdit = this.dialog.open(DialogGizmo,
      {
        width: "300px",
        data: { },
      });

    dialogEdit.afterClosed()
      .pipe(map(x => {
        if (x !== false) {
          gizmo.value = x.GizmoValue;
          gizmo.description = x.GizmoDescription;
        }
      }))
      .subscribe(x => {
      if (x !== undefined) {
        this.dataCatalogService.addGizmo(gizmo)
        .subscribe(
          () => this.loadGizmos(),
          error => this.handleError(error)
        );
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` pipe returns undefined.
Add `return x` in the end of your map.

```
dialogEdit.afterClosed()
  .pipe(map(x => {
    if (x !== false) {
      gizmo.value = x.GizmoValue;
      gizmo.description = x.GizmoDescription;
    }
    return x;  // THIS LINE
  }))
  .subscribe(x => {
  if (x !== undefined) {
    this.dataCatalogService.addGizmo(gizmo)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.loadGizmos(),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
});
```

`map` pipe takes value and should return any result you need to be passes to further pipes.
Learn more about `map` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

P.S. Seems that you actually don't need `map` pipe here because you are not transforming incoming value. Take a look on `do / tap` [operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html).

Comment: You also shouln't be using `map` anyway, if you're not mapping your values. Use `do`/`tap` instead.

Comment: @ritaj I agree. Just answered the question in scope of given conditions. Will extend my answer with your tips.

Comment: Thank you I switched over to the the tap and added the return and it working.

Comment: @JDS if you use use `tap` you can leave without `return` because `tap` is made for "side effects" and returned value will not influence on further pipes. :)

Answer (score 0):

As [@ArtemArkhipov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5075755/artem-arkhipov) answered, you're not returning anything in your `map` function.

While it should resolve your issue, I think you can improve your code readability like so

```html
<!-- Not returning something will return '' -->
<button color="primary" mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
<button color="primary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="gizmo">{{inEditMode === true ? "Save" : "Add"}}</button>
```

```js
dialogEdit.afterClosed()
  .pipe(
    // filter : if the response is falsy, don't go further ('' is falsy)
    filter(res => !!res),
    // tap the answer, because you don't want to change it, only update your variable
    tap(x => {
      gizmo.value = x.GizmoValue;
      gizmo.description = x.GizmoDescription;
    }),
    // Use mergeMap to chain another HTTP call and get rid of one subscribe
    mergeMap(x => this.dataCatalogService.addGizmo(gizmo))
  ).subscribe(
    () => this.loadGizmos(),
    error => this.handleError(error)
  )
);
```

This reduces your code and improves its readability. Without comments it gives

```js
dialogEdit.afterClosed()
  .pipe(
    filter(res => !!res),
    tap(x => {
      gizmo.value = x.GizmoValue;
      gizmo.description = x.GizmoDescription;
    }),
    mergeMap(x => this.dataCatalogService.addGizmo(gizmo))
  ).subscribe(
    () => this.loadGizmos(),
    error => this.handleError(error)
  )
);
```